# Vue Js 2 Error when import App.Vue in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2015, vue.js, vuejs2

I am total new to Vue JS, I created a new project in Visual studio 2015. I haven't find any tutorial on web which can give you an idea how Vue js works with asp.net MVC in visual studio 2015. I followed all the steps need to work on Vue. I am using web pack simple template. All commands are according to their official website.

```
npm install -g vue-cli
```

created a new project using the "webpack" template

```
vue init webpack my-project
```

install dependencies and go!

```
cd my-project

npm install
```

It did creates every thing for me. but when i ran it it give me an error debug mode at console

```
Unexpected token {
   at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:404:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\users\*******************\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\VueProject\VueProject\node_modules\vue-loader\index.js:1:80)
    at Module._compile (module.js:397:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:404:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at loadLoader (c:\users\*******************\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\VueProject\VueProject\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js:13:17)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (c:\users\*******************\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\VueProject\VueProject\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at runLoaders (c:\users\*******************\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\VueProject\VueProject\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:362:2)
    at NormalModule.doBuild (c:\users\*******************\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\VueProject\VueProject\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:182:3)
    at NormalModule.build (c:\users\*******************\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\VueProject\VueProject\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:275:15)
    at Compilation.buildModule (c:\users\*******************\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\VueProject\VueProject\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:151:10)
    at factoryCallback (c:\users\*******************\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\VueProject\VueProject\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:344:12)
    at c:\users\*******************\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\VueProject\VueProject\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:241:5
    at c:\users\*******************\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\VueProject\VueProject\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:94:13
    at c:\users\*******************\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\VueProject\VueProject\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:268:11
    at NormalModuleFactory.<anonymous> (c:\users\*******************\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\VueProject\VueProject\node_modules\webpack\lib\CompatibilityPlugin.js:52:5)
    at NormalModuleFactory.applyPluginsAsyncWaterfall (c:\users\*******************\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\VueProject\VueProject\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:272:13)
    at c:\users\*******************\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\VueProject\VueProject\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:69:10
    at c:\users\*******************\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\VueProject\VueProject\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:194:7
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:452:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:381:13)
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:404:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\users\*******************\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\VueProject\VueProject\node_modules\vue-loader\index.js:1:80)
    at Module._compile (module.js:397:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:404:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at loadLoader (c:\users\*******************\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\VueProject\VueProject\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js:13:17)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (c:\users\*******************\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\VueProject\VueProject\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at runLoaders (c:\users\*******************\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\VueProject\VueProject\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:362:2)
    at NormalModule.doBuild (c:\users\*******************\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\VueProject\VueProject\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:182:3)
    at NormalModule.build (c:\users\*******************\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\VueProject\VueProject\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:275:15)
    at Compilation.buildModule (c:\users\*******************\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\VueProject\VueProject\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:151:10)
    at factoryCallback (c:\users\*******************\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\VueProject\VueProject\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:344:12)
    at c:\users\*******************\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\VueProject\VueProject\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:241:5
    at c:\users\*******************\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\VueProject\VueProject\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:94:13
    at c:\users\*******************\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\VueProject\VueProject\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:268:11
    at NormalModuleFactory.<anonymous> (c:\users\*******************\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\VueProject\VueProject\node_modules\webpack\lib\CompatibilityPlugin.js:52:5)
    at NormalModuleFactory.applyPluginsAsyncWaterfall (c:\users\*******************\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\VueProject\VueProject\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:272:13)
    at c:\users\*******************\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\VueProject\VueProject\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:69:10
    at c:\users\*******************\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\VueProject\VueProject\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:194:7
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:452:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:381:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:1457/dist/build.js:6:34888)
    at t (http://localhost:1457/dist/build.js:1:101)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:1457/dist/build.js:1:718)
    at t (http://localhost:1457/dist/build.js:1:101)
    at http://localhost:1457/dist/build.js:1:457
    at http://localhost:1457/dist/build.js:1:466
```